# Generating and adding a new class to an existing assembly in runtime

Tags: c#

According to MSDN it's possible to create a NEW assembly in runtime using, for example, `Reflection.Emit` and add a new class in it, I just would like to avoid such an overkill and create the class in an existing assembly.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't alter existing assemblies, as they are read-only once they are loaded (not to mention the problem of strong name signing). There is generally no disadvantage to creating a new assembly; what prevents you from doing so?

Comment: I just thought it would be an overkill (maybe slow, maybe too much memory consumption, etc.) to create a new assembly just for the sake of creating one single class, but OK, I'll try it. Thanks for the answer.